# Outlook 2007: Automatic Flag Rule OR Sort Related Email Conversations

Tags: windows, email, microsoft-outlook-2007

My company is using Microsoft Outlook 2007.  Here's a quick breakdown of what we are doing, and what I'm looking to do:

1) a mechanic sends an email to a specific contact group requesting parts (lets call the group 'PARTSGROUP' and the email subject is 'TEST'

2) one of the 7 people in PARTSGROUP 'replies to all' for said email (replies to mechanic and PARTSGROUP saying they are taking care of it...ie - "TEST - DONE").  Once someone in PARTSGROUP 'claims' that email by replying "DONE" to the rest of the group, the conversation continues between ONLY the assigned mechanic and parts person.

Currently I have a rule set up to send all emails sent to PARTSGROUP to go to the PartsGroup folder to make sorting through hundreds of them a day slightly easier.   TEST01 & TEST01 - DONE.  TEST02 & TEST02 - DONE, etc.

IDEALLY I'd like for the original email the mechanic sends to the group address to automatically be flagged - this would make sorting through 'claimed' emails much easier...  please help!